# How to get the Freebase Python libraries to work in IronPython

Tags: ironpython, freebase

How do I get the [Python libraries for using the Freebase API](http://code.google.com/p/freebase-python/) to work under [IronPython 2.0](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython)?

When I "import freebase.api", I get "ImportError: No module named django.utils". What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the simplejson module. Since easy_install doesn't yet work with IronPython, your best bet is to grab the latest code using SVN from their [Google Code project](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/source/checkout), or [download a zip file](http://apiguy.com/files/simplejson-2.0.9.zip).

Put all of the files that you obtained into the lib/site-packages/simplejson folder under your IronPython installation directory.

Now you'll be able to successfully "import freebase.api".